Self-Cancelling Task Inhibits other Instances
I am trying to make a subclass of Task that cancels itself and waits when it is disposed.
While unit testing I got strange failing test cases. In the end it boiled down to repetition; I could even run the same test multiple times and get a pass only in the first run.
Here's the code for my AutoCancelTask class (sorry for the rather long code... I tried to make a minimum functional example that you can copy-paste...):
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace Tests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A Task that is cancelled and waited for, when disposed.
    /// </summary>
    public class AutoCancelTask : Task
    {
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;

        private AutoCancelTask(Action<CancellationToken> action, CancellationTokenSource cts, TaskCreationOptions options)
            : base(() => action(cts.Token), cts.Token, options)
        {
            _cts = cts;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Wrap a cancellable Action in a Task that is automatically cancelled and waited for when disposed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="action">The Action to wrap.</param>
        /// <param name="options">The TaskCreationOptions to use.</param>
        /// <returns>The started task.</returns>
        public static Task Run(Action<CancellationToken> action, TaskCreationOptions options = TaskCreationOptions.None)
        {
            Task t = new AutoCancelTask(action, new CancellationTokenSource(), options);
            t.Start();
            return t;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                try
                {
                    _cts.Cancel();
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException)
                {
                    // nothing to do in this case
                }
                try
                {
                    Wait();
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException) { }
                catch (AggregateException ex)
                {
                    if (1 < ex.InnerExceptions.Count || false == (ex.InnerExceptions[0] is TaskCanceledException))
                    {
                        // rethrow if the aggregate does not contain a single TaskCancelledException
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
                _cts.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}

And here's my test class
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace Tests
{
    public class TestDataWrapper
    {
        internal bool? IsCancelled { get; private set; } = null;
        internal void Action(CancellationToken cancel)
        {
            IsCancelled = Task.Delay(100, cancel).ContinueWith(t => t.IsCanceled).Result;
        }
    }

    [TestClass()]
    public class Tests
    {
        public static IEnumerable<object[]> Datas { get; } =
            Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(_ => new object[] { new TestDataWrapper() });

        [DataTestMethod]
        [DynamicData(nameof(Datas))]
        public void AutoCancelTask_Cancels(TestDataWrapper data)
        {
            using (AutoCancelTask.Run(data.Action)) { }
            Assert.AreEqual(true, data.IsCancelled);
        }
    }
}

Obviously, I'm expecting the test case to pass. However, only the first execution passes, while the other ones fail with the message Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<True>. Actual:<(null)>..
Interestingly, execution time varies too:
Run 1: ~30ms
Run 2: ~300ms
Run 4-5: <1ms
As the result is null and not false, I suspect the issue to be somewhere in the task being cancelled before the action is even started. However, this puzzles me, as I don't use anything static or otherwise shared between the test runs.
To make sure I understand the ContinueWith expression correctly, I tried replacing the Action method with the following:
internal void Action(CancellationToken cancel)
{
    Task t = Task.Delay(100, cancel);
    try
    {
        t.Wait();
    }
    catch
    {
        // ignore
    }
    IsCancelled = t.IsCanceled;
    t.Dispose();
}

That yields the same results.
I then tried to spam my class with debug output, and suddenly I got all test runs passed. It also works when I add a delay in the Dispose method exactly here:
if (disposing)
{
    try
    {
        Delay(1).Wait(); // <-- this fixes it
        _cts.Cancel();
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        // nothing to do in this case
    }
}

Which hardens my suspicion that a subsequent task can not start too soon after another has cancelled...
I'd rather avoid that delay there, as it seems not correct to me. Can you shed some light for me what is happening here?

Don't build such a class. The API isn't broken. A Task isn't a job, or thread, it's a Promise that something can complete in the Future. It does not execute the work itself. Cancelling that promise isn't the job of the promise that whatever processes it.  Other languages call their equivalent types Promise or Future. They don't mix cancellation with the promise itself

@PanagiotisKanavos there are two types of tasks, delegate-based tasks and promise-style tasks. The OP is authoring a custom delegate-based task, i.e. a task associated with a delegate. It's not an abstract promise/future. It represents the execution of a specific delegate.

That's not what I was talking at all, which I assumed you'd understand. I was talking about the concept of tasks in general and the equivalent  in other languages. At this point it's far more likely that people know about a JavaScript Promise than a .NET Task

@PanagiotisKanavos this is a C# question. Assuming that someone who asks a C# question is more accustomed to terms and concepts found in other languages is absurd to be honest. I'm not seeing the slightest hint that would justify such an assumption. The OP is a new member of the site, with zero history of asking or answering questions, and with no bio information whatsoever.

Your tasks are most likely cancelled before they get the chance to run. Starting a task
will put it on a queue for later execution. In this test you are cancelling the task immediately after creation.
So when the task is picked up for execution, its cancellation token is checked, and if cancelled, it is just set directly to cancelled status. So data.Action is never run, and you flag never set. Adding a delay will give the framework enough time to start executing the task.
Note that this approach seem to be highly susceptible to deadlocks. If you use this AutoCancelTask on the UI thread, and the task needs to dispatch anything to the same UI thread, you will get a deadlock.  The task cannot complete since it waits for the UI thread, and the UI thread cannot continue, since it is waiting for the task.
The correct approach will depend on what you are trying to do. I would try to avoid inheriting from Task, since I think it will cause confusion. For example, It is fairly common to not bother disposing tasks, so if you add behavior to dispose you risk bugs if someone else are not aware of your special class. If you are on c# 8+ you can use IAsyncDisposable to allow awaiting in dispose methods and that might help in some use cases.

Not just confusion, the concept is completely different. A Task is a Promise, not an execution. Languages and libraries that support promises don't mix them up with cancellation. The OP is trying to create a Thread, not a Task

@JonasH As to why the data.Action has no chance to run, I think I understand your explanation. But then again... why does the first execution not fail as well?
@PanagiotisKanavos I did indeed think of Task as just a more modern construct for Thread. My motivation for creating this class was that I was often implementing a worker loop in a Task (such as a log writer) in a class and a CancellationTokenSource alongside it. Then, when disposing, cancel the source and wait for the task to complete before disposing it. It seemed neat to me to wrap that pattern in its own class.

It's not a thread and what you describe isn't really pattern. If you want to process an infinite stream of messages you can use ActionBlock. Or you can use a Channel and use await foreach(var msg in thatChannelReader.ReadAllAsync()), or Parallel.ForEachAsync(thatChannel.....) if you want to process multiple messages concurrently.

@GreatBarrier anything that uses threads will be subject to variances of timing, so there will be no guarantees if the task is started or not. If you observe any consistent behavior it is due to implementation details. It would not be unreasonable with a base class for background processing, but do not inherit from Task. Create your own base class, use IAsyncDisposable, and consider using existing libraries like dataflow or Channels instead.

Thank you @JonasH, that makes sense. I'll accept your answer here. As for the other Types @PanagiotisKanavos suggested, both ActionBlock and Channel were new to me (I'm stuck in the past with wpf, .net framework and whatever was modern at the time :) ). I will have a look at those and experiment a bit.
Thank you both for the time you took for wrapping your head around what I came up with!

@GreatBarrier ActionBlock is part of DataFlow. That, and quite a few new patterns can be used in .net framework if you include the libraries and/or use the latest langversion. But there will be some things that just require a newer runtime.

Indeed, some things require IAsyncEnumerable which was introduced in C# 8. They can be backported to .NET Framework using the `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces package.

private AutoCancelTask(
    Action<CancellationToken> action,
    CancellationTokenSource cts,
    TaskCreationOptions options)
        : base(() => action(cts.Token), cts.Token, options)

You are passing the cancelation token to the constructor of the base Task class. This means that in case the cancellation token is canceled before the action is executed by the TaskScheduler, the execution will be canceled. I.e. the action will not be invoked. The official documentation is not clear about this behavior, and I had to dig quite a bit into the .NET source code to find why the action is not invoked, although the task has been already scheduled for execution with the Start method (which schedules the task with the TaskScheduler.Current, which is usually the TaskScheduler.Default, which is the internal ThreadPoolTaskScheduler class). The relevant source code files are these two:

Task.cs
TaskScheduler.cs

So if you pass the token to the Task constructor, you'll have to deal with the possibility that the action will not be invoked.
As for the reason why the test succeeds the first time, I am not exactly sure but my guess is that the ThreadPool wins the race to execute the delegate before the .NET Jitter completes the compilation of the AutoCancelTask.Dispose method that contains the  _cts.Cancel(); command. The Jitter has to do this only once, which explains the observed behavior. But I might be wrong.

Wow, the Jitter... That too seems quite plausible! I tried to force the Jitter to run again for each test with that Test method:
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(20)]
[DataRow(30)]
[DataRow(40)]
[DataRow(50)]
public void AutoCancelTask_Cancels_Repeatedly_When_Jitter_Is_Forced(int msDelay)
{
    bool? result = null;
    using (AutoCancelTask.Run(token => result = Task.Delay(msDelay, token).ContinueWith(t => t.IsCanceled).Result)) { }
    Assert.AreEqual(true, result);
}

However, that seems to be not enough... Maybe completely different tasks instead of different timeouts?

Hehe... Code formatting in the comments is a no-go. Sorry about that...

@GreatBarrier whatever is the exact reason, there is obviously a race condition, and you don't want to have race conditions in the application or library that you author.

True, and I totally aggree. I will rewrite the AutoCancelTask class. However, I strive to understand the mechanisms of the Framework I use as deeply as I possibly can. That's why I tried to find reasons why my test behaved this way. Again, also to you I give my thanks for the time you invested in researching and answering my question. I'd even accept both answers, if SO permitted this :)
